# Passing a django dictionary ( or json file) to javascript function

Tags: javascript, django

I know there are a few ways to access django variables in javascript .However I am not able to send a django dictionary or json object to javascript .
My code :
view.py

```
items_raw = Items.objects.all() 
items = list(items_raw.values())
return render(request,'admin_dashboard/products.html',{'items':json.dump(items)})
```

Template :

```
{% for item in items %}
      <tr>
         <td><a onclick=edit_product("{{item|safe}}")>{{ item.product_name }}</a></td> 
  {%endfor%}
<!--- JAVASCRIPT HERE ---!>
<script>
function edit_product(item){
console.log(item.id) }
</script>
```

Here "items" is a json object which is a list of dictionaries (the dict has more than 20 keys and values ) there are thousands of item in list . I only want to pass the particular item user selected to js function . Is there any simple way to do it ?

1. I don't want to include serializers or rest-framework .
2. I don't care for security ,I will be the only one using this .
3. I don't want to put all 20 pairs of the dictionary in html like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myVar" name="variable" data-prod="{{ item.product_name }}" data-id="{{ item.id }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

By django dictionary, I'm assuming you mean a queryset. You can accomplish what you want by adding a to_json function on the model of your queryset. It should look something like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):  
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)    
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)  
    to_json(self):  
        return {  
            'field1': self.field1,  
            'field2': self.field2,   
       }
```

This is an alternative to using a serializer. Ideally you would pass this data as json to your frontend."

Comment: It's not a query set , I have already made the query into a json object . 
```
items_raw = Items.objects.all() 
items = list(items_raw.values())
return render(request,'admin_dashboard/products.html',  {'items':items})
```
But I still can't pass this :
```
{% for item in items %}
      <tr>
         <td><a onclick=edit_product("{{item|safe}}")>{{ item.product_name }}</a></td> 
  {%endfor%}
```